# How should I list the conferences and courses I attend as an undergrad student to my CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, conference, cv, workshop

This is not really a duplicate of this question: [Should I list conferences I attended on my CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30041/should-i-list-conferences-i-attended-on-my-cv)

I just finish my bachelor and trying to apply to a grad school. Of course, my CV is weak and strong LORs are what I should count on. However, I do want to strengthen my CV, so I want to list some conferences and courses that I have attended. So far, I have attended:

- A specialty workshop held in my university. Actively helping behind the scene (put letters into envelops, be a reception, etc). Unfortunately I don't remember exactly the detail, but I can seek for help.
- An international flagship conference held by a reputable institute in my country. I just sit back and listened, and unfortunately didn't register to attend.
- An annual conference held by my university. This one was opened for any specialty, and I had a poster presentation in there.
- An course taught by an invited professor from Germany, with h-index was 36. This course was organized at the same time with the workshop.

Should I list them down to my CV? How should do it properly?

Comment: I notice that this may be too local. But I don't want to spam the site with 5 questions at the same time.

Comment: I would only list activities that you actually did something concrete at. Definitely presenting a poster, maybe if you helped with administrative work at a workshop, probably not if you just attended.

Comment: @RogerFan thanks again. I have raised a question about the poster in the comment in Nate's answer. Can you come and join?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would suggest you include these in the CV for a graduate application.  It probably won't make a huge difference in admissions, but it is evidence that you are interested and involved in the research community in your field.

You can list them in any way that seems appropriate; there's no strict standard format for a CV.  You probably have sections for "Education" and "Work experience" and maybe "Publications"; make a similar section entitled "Conferences attended" or "Conference participation" or something like that.  Include the title, date and location of each conference, and maybe a short sentence discussing the scope of the meeting and your role.

(As discussed in the question you linked: later in your career, you will probably want to take this section out.)

Comment: Thank you again. However, about the poster, I have already mentioned this work as a paper to submit this conference in the *Research Experience* section, and as a dissertation in the *Education* section. I have asked about [this duplication](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32912/should-i-list-my-work-as-dissertation-or-conference-paper). I'm afraid that if I continue to list it, the recruiters will think that I'm trying to inflate the work.